# Is it possible to call Thread start() and join() in a single call?

Tags: java, multithreading, join

I'm playing with threads in Java and i have a question about the join() method.
Let's say i have a SampleClass that extends Thread. I instantiate some new threads in the main but i want the thread's job to be completed sequentially using join().

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        new SampleClass().start();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to call immediately join()? ...something like this:

```
new SampleClass().start().join();
```

Or is there another approach to use? ...like this maybe:

```
new SampleClass().start();
try{Thread.currentThread().join();}catch(InterruptedException e){...}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Umm ... this question could be answered by spending 2 minutes reading the javadocs.

Comment: I have looked here 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29
but i have not found any info useful to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new SampleClass().start().join(); This is wrong.
```

You can achieve similar thing by

```
   SampleClass samClass = new SampleClass();
   samClass.start();
   samClass.join()
```

The above code will have same effect as you wanted.

Now your problem is to run the Threads Sequentially. **In most of these 
   cases you don't need threads to execute sequentially (But yes there are some scenarios).
   Well If you do have to.**

Then you can Do Like this

```
   Thread t1 = ..
   Thread t2 = ..

   t1.start();
   t1.join();
   t2.start(); // t2 will start only when t1 dies
   t2.join(); //  
   t3.start(); // t3 will start only when t2 dies..
```

**But the above approach is not good. Because for other thread to start, previous thread
     needs to die. In practice We should think of creating threads as an expensive operation 
     and try to reuse**.

The real problem often is like this, You have to execute tasks T1 , T2 , T3 , T4 
   sequentially but in different Threads T1 && T3 have to run on one threads and T2 and T4 
   have to run on another.
   So here we can use Two threads instead of 4. 
   Thread1 will run T1 and then Thread2 will run T2 and then Thread1 will run T3 and so on
   i.e.

```
Thread1 -> T1
Thread2 -> T2
Thread1 -> T3
Thread2 -> T4
```

All  task will be executed sequentially but using 2 threads only.

You can solve the problem like below

```
  Thread1 ->run {
    while(canIrun) {
    executeTask(taskQueue1.next());
    notifyThread2();
    waitForThread2Signal();
   }
  }

  Thread2 -.run {
   while(canIrun) {
    waitForThread1Signal();
    executeTask(taskQueue2.next());
    notifyThread1();
   }
  }
```

The wait and notify method can be implemented using CyclicBarrier very easily.

Comment: Thank you for your time, for writing some examples and giving some explanation. :-)

Answer (score 2):

What would be the point? You can get the same *effect,* without the overhead, by just calling run().

Comment: +1 - Good point.  Starting a thread and immediately joining it negates any benefit you might get from using a thread in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to call immediately join()?

No it is not as [start()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29) returns `void` . You cannot chain those methods that way. And you need to invoke [join()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) on a `Thread` object.

Comment: Ok thanks so chaining is not possible. Given that the threads are instantiated anonimously how is it possible (if possible) to call the join() method? Thread.currentThread().join(); seems to work but not as i was expecting.

The first thread instance is created, it completes the work but then nothing else happens (the other threads are not instantiated like the FOR only runs once).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ExecutorService#submit(Runnable runnable).get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

Answer (score 0):

Method start belongs to Thread class. It would be like doing this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(someRunnableTask);
//This fails to compile, because start returns NOTHING (void). This variable will not be filled with pointer to our thread object.
Thread ourOriginalThreadPointer = thread.start();
//Hence this variable references to nothing, no method can be called.
ourOriginalThreadPointer.join()
```

Comment: Err, that's the *question,* not the answer. The point is that `start()` returns void so your code doesn't compile, any more than the OP's. -1

Comment: It should explain WHY it doesn't compile for the one who asked to know how it works. Learn to read. I say there it won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

The instanciated thread doesn't need to be anonymous. You can do that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        SampleClass sc = new SampleClass();
        sc.start();
        try {
            sc.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```